# Proper way to delete contents of directory

Tags: filesystems, rm

What is the proper way to delete **all** the contents of a directory, without said directory?
For example, I have the following directory structure:

```
foo/
    bar1/
    bar2/
    x.txt
```

I want to delete the folders `bar1` and `bar2` and the file `x.txt`, **without deleting** `foo`.

Also please consider file names with special characters that may be ignored or raise an error.

---

**Edit #1 (30 Sep, 18:26 UTC):**
I think that my question isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45950/how-to-remove-only-the-content-of-directories), because that I asked to delete **everything** inside a directory, while the other question didn't and the answers didn't include such solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the directory you can do using one of these commands:

```
$ find foo/* -delete

$ rm -fr foo/*

$ find foo/* -exec rm -fr {} +
```

If you have files that start with a dot (`.`) then you'll need a modified version of `rm`.

```
$ rm -fr foo/{*,.*}
```

#### Example

```
$ ls -l foo
drwxrwxr-x    6 saml saml  4096 Sep 27 09:43 .
drwx------. 263 saml saml 32768 Sep 27 09:42 ..
drwxrwxr-x    2 saml saml  4096 Sep 27 09:43 dir1
drwxrwxr-x    2 saml saml  4096 Sep 27 09:43 dir2
drwxrwxr-x    2 saml saml  4096 Sep 27 09:43 dir space1
drwxrwxr-x    2 saml saml  4096 Sep 27 09:43 dir space2
-rw-rw-r--    1 saml saml     0 Sep 27 09:43 .dot space1
-rw-rw-r--    1 saml saml     0 Sep 27 09:43 .dot space2
-rw-rw-r--    1 saml saml     0 Sep 27 09:43 file1
-rw-rw-r--    1 saml saml     0 Sep 27 09:43 file2
-rw-rw-r--    1 saml saml     0 Sep 27 09:43 file space1
-rw-rw-r--    1 saml saml     0 Sep 27 09:43 file space2

$ rm -fr foo/{*,.*}
rm: cannot remove directory: `adir/.'
rm: cannot remove directory: `adir/..'
$

$ ls -l foo/
total 0
$
```

Repeating with a fresh directory of files:

```
$ find foo/* -delete
$
```

#### Dealing with special characters

If you have a directory named `foo tastic` that has a space you can quote it but still use a wildcard:

#### Example

```
$ rm -fr "foo tastic"/*
```

#### Special Characters

I'll often use this trick to see what the shell thinks of my filename concoctions prior to running them. In the sample directory I used above:

$ ls -1 "file "*
file space1
file space2

$ ls -1d "dir "*
dir space1
dir space2

By doing these tests before hand you can get a sense of what files/directories will be in play when a command containing the glob is used.

Comment: Thank you! What is the meaning of `{*,.*}` in the first example? Wouldn't `rm -fr foo/*` be dangerous? Because of the wildcard `*`

Comment: It deletes files that match * or .*. Sometimes there are files that start with a . (`.`). These won't match the * glob.

Comment: Could you also please use quotes? I've tried `rm -R "./foo/*"` but it gives an error.

Comment: @Dor - No you can't quote that because of the *. If you have files with crazy characters I'd use the find variant.

Comment: @sim: But what if instead of `foo` I have a folder path that uses special characters?

Comment: `rm -R "./foo a space"/*`

Comment: @Dor - I've added some examples about this to tha A too.